# How can I tell If a DNS server is replying authoritatively?

Tags: dns, domain-name

Well, I do not control the DNS, and I will like to know if that DNS is replying with the "correct" ip address for a domain name, and also to check if that particular DNS is replying authoritatively?

Comment: You could use nslookup tool (available with Windows). It is a command line based tool. Just open a cmd in an elevated command prompt, type nslookup domainname.xxx and press enter. Your DNS server (local) will display the IP address related to the domain. This is the DNS look up method. You could also use https://www.ultratools.com (tools provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if it is the 'correct' IP address, after using `nslookup` as stated by the above poster, you would use WHOIS and compare the two.  Unless your DNS is not ISP directed there is little chance they would be different.